# Setting Up Chainlink Node with Linux Arm64 Chrome duet

Tags: validation, blockchain, arm64, chainlink

I want to set up a chainlink node. I have a chrome duet linux Arm64. does this prevent me from setting up Chainlink node.

I installed Docker.

I set up the environment, ethereum feed, and database per docs.

Then I run this command:

cd ~/.chainlink-rinkeby && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-rinkeby:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink:0.10.9 local n

I choose a version from Chainlink Hub link. But all I can see is AMD64.

This is the output I get:

WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error

Does anyone know what I can do next? thanks

Answer (score 0):

All of the supported systems are listed [on the docker page](https://hub.docker.com/r/smartcontract/chainlink/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated). If your system isn't supported, perhaps you can try installing go etc and trying to build from source?

Comment: I want to do my own research, but I need clarification. I am a newbie in coding. I found that I can build my own image for docker using the go language. I will research and learn that. But what did you mean build from the source, because wouldn't I need to use a version from the docker page? Or once I build a docker container using the arm64 compatible image, how do I start the chainlink node? I'm sorry I don't know if what I'm saying is making any sense.

Comment: Or am I trying to build an amd64 image for docker using go language? then use the compatible amd64 version from the Chainlink docker page? Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated. I think Chainlink is revolutionary and I want to be apart of it! thanks for your time, much respect!!

Comment: a chainlink node docker image is just an already compiled chainlink node, ready to start, you don't need Go or any other dependencies installed. to 'build from source' means you don't use docker at all, and you download and install Go, nodejs etc and then follow the steps in the chainlink README to compile and then execute the code yourself. So it's not in a container, its running on your computer like a normal program